# About $\Bbb {proj}_U \Bbb v$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, projection

Let $V$ be an inner product space. Let $U \subseteq V$ and $U^{\perp} \subseteq V$.

Then I know that for any $\Bbb v \in V$, we can write a uniq form of $\Bbb v = u_1 + u_2$,

such that $u_1 \in U$ and $u_2 \in U^{\perp}$, while we know that $u_1 = \Bbb {proj}_U \Bbb v$.

So $\Bbb v = \Bbb {proj}_U \Bbb v +(\Bbb v - \Bbb {proj}_U \Bbb v)$

My question is:

Is that correct to write  $\Bbb {proj}_{U^{\perp}} \Bbb v = \Bbb v - \Bbb {proj}_U \Bbb v$

So $\Bbb v = \Bbb {proj}_U \Bbb v + \Bbb {proj}_{U^{\perp}} \Bbb v~~$ ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, the direct sum decomposition $V = U \oplus U^{\perp}$ you are talking about does not hold for arbitrary inner product space $V$ and subspace $U$. It always holds if, for example, $V$ is finite dimensional or $V$ is a Hilbert space and $U$ is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. By the way that you have defined $\operatorname{proj}_U(v)$, you have$$\operatorname{proj}_{U^\perp}(v)=u_2=v-u_1=v-\operatorname{proj}_U(v).$$And therefore you have indeed that$$v=\operatorname{proj}_U(v)+\operatorname{proj}_{U^\perp}(v).$$

Comment: Great, thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: You always help me! :D

Comment: I think the result is true only in finite dimensional inner product spaces. Correct me if I’m wrong please.

Comment: @LawrenceMano Yes. I forget to say that I was assuming that. In infinite dimension, we may have $U\ne V$ and $U^\perp=\{0\}$.